# Sliding View + appbar (coordinator layout)

Tags: android, scroll, android-coordinatorlayout

I'm trying to reproduce the sliding view's logic, which should be similar as in my IOS app.

I was able to make the first when scrolling up - only AppBar is hidden. View, which is under it - remains at the top of the screen and is not hidden.

But I need it as in the video - the first when you scroll up to hide it under the View, and only then - AppBar.

Tell me, is it possible to do this with the help of coordinator layout or is it necessary to write additional logic in the code?

[Video HERE](https://youtu.be/Zye8_ujvc3o)

Comment: "This video is unavailable"

Comment: We can't see the video. Try to show it in other way

Comment: Just fixed it. Please try click video link again. Ty.